# Change on the state of one component is affecting others (from same type)

Tags: reactjs

Having several components from the same type in one page, when changing the state of one of them it's affecting all!

[image]

```
state = {
    ...,
    projectErrorMessage: 'NA'
};


{ this.state.projectErrorMessage !== null ?
                                /*<Warning20 id={'ProjectError.'+this.props.project.Name} className="Error" alt={this.state.projectErrorMessage}/>*/
                                <Tooltip direction="bottom" renderIcon={Warning20} className="Error">
                                    <p>
                                        {this.state.projectErrorMessage}
                                    </p>
                                </Tooltip>
                            : null}
```

If I clear the project error message from one component, it clean it from all!

I'm passing the key inside from the wrapper component:

```
 <div className="inline">
                        {filteredProjects.map(item =>
                            <Project
                                key={item.Name}
                                project={item}
```

Sandbox with all code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-morning-267l5

Comment: Can you show us some more code? Or a reproducible example?

Comment: I added a link to a sandbox with the app... If I change the state.projectErrorMessage or the props.project.Name of one component, it will affect all others!

Comment: The sandbox project does not even let me change the name, and how to I trigger a projectMessage

Comment: I added a new option to the top right menu: clear error, and then I realized that the issue doesn't occur from this scenario, it happens only when I call the api (will not work from sandbox cause api is deployed only locally). Once the api call pass successfully I do a clear error via EventEmitter (see cleanProjectError() from RestService.js under store folder ) this symptom happens!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every project component listens to service.on("projectErrorClean", this.cleanProjectError);, so if that is called, all errors are cleared. You should pass the id of the cleared error to the service, so that only the one component with the matching id clears its errors. Same for all the other services. Hope this helps.